# SFrame for Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.4, anaconda, pypi, sframe

On the [project's website](https://github.com/turi-code/SFrame) it tells me, that there is Python 3.4 support (Readme.md, which is shown as text on that page). However, I fail to see where I could get that Python 3.4 compatible version of SFrame from. It's not on anaconda and not on PyPI, where I only see Python 2.7 versions.

So I wonder, if they simply didn't update their Readme.md to note the fact, that SFrame is not available for Python 3.4 anymore, or if it is somewhere, where I didn't find it. Why should they note that there is no support for Python 3.5.x yet after all, if they didn't have it for 3.4.

I did install it for a Python 3.4.5 anaconda environment before and if I recall correctly, that was from PyPI, so I am thinking they took it down from there for some reason.

Does anyone know how to get a Python 3.4 compatible version of SFrame into an anaconda environment today?

Comment: did you fix that, i have the same problem with python 3.5.2

Comment: @ChediBechikh I could never solve it. I think it's simply not available for download anymore anywhere, they commercialized it.